# Cropping a bitmap evenly from all corners

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap with width 720 and height 1020 I want to crop all four corners of the bitmap with the same value say 50. So 50 from top, left, bottom and right. Here is how I have tried this in my code

```
sourceImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceImg, 50,
                            50, sourceImg.getWidth() - 50, sourceImg.getHeight() - 50);
```

The top and left seem to crop properly but the bottom and right do not.

Comment: If the top and left are cropping correctly, it would seem that you need to subtract just `corner` from the last two parameters, not `corner/2`.

Comment: Edited the question to avoid any confusion. Could you explain why I would need to change the value I'm cropping out of the bitmap for right and bottom?

Comment: The last two parameters, IIRC, aren't right and bottom, they're width and height. So if the top and left are 50, and you want an even border all around, you need the width and height to be 2 * 50 less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the calculation below. Width and height are decreased by corner value (half from each side).

```
sourceImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceImg, 
    corner/2, 
    corner/2, 
    sourceImg.getWidth() - corner, 
    sourceImg.getHeight() - corner);
```

Comment: Works fine now. Now I understand the reason why I need to do it this way. Thanks